# Creating a regex to find corruption

Tags: regex, sequence, corruption, repeat

> kŸkŸkŸkŸkŸkŸkŸkŸkŸkŸkŸkŸkŸkŸkŸkŸkŸkŸkŸkŸkQOzW Îžò4d1|l»ÏAñ?:"ñl¦£.._ÇŸf€À?Lƒ,ðe¿íÏ”.á¢..ü¾bÜW!jà×

considered corrupted is:

> kŸkŸkŸkŸkŸk
>   FFFFFFF
>   oŸoŸoŸoŸoŸoŸoŸoŸoŸoŸo

*Pretty much any 2 bit sequence repeated.*

I cant for the life of me think up a way of detecting it without detecting everything else - the real issue is not detecting `(kŸ{2,})` but detecting any other possibility.

Comment: Please, ask a question :) It would help a lot if you stated well: 1) what coding language you are using 2) what you are seeking for EXACTLY, because kŸ is not a sequence of 2 bytes-if it were, there would be the same (single) character repeated

Comment: @PaoloStefan, I agree about the two byte issue, but the question here seems pretty clear: how to detect an arbitrary repeating sequence.

Comment: Sorry I meant two bits. Obviously detecting 2 bytes would be possible. Anyway the question could have been "how to detect 2 bytes sequences with regex"

Answer (score 3):

This regex will match a repeated *two character* sequence:

```
/(..)\1+/
```

**Explanation:**

`(..)` matches any two characters, putting them in the first capture group.

`\1` refers to the first capture group, so it will check if the same two characters repeat